# Getting a 2D histogram of a grayscale image in Julia

Tags: image-processing, julia

Using the Images package, I can open up a color image, convert it to Gray scale and then :

```
using Images
img_gld = imread("...path to some color jpg...")
img_gld_gs = convert(Image{Gray},img_gld)
#change from floats to Array of values between 0 and 255:
img_gld_gs = reinterpret(Uint8,data(img_gld_gs))
```

Now I've got a 1920X1080 array of Uint8's:

```
julia> img_gld_gs 
1920x1080 Array{Uint8,2}
```

Now I want to get a histogram of the 2D array of Uint8 values:

```
julia> hist(img_gld_gs)
(0.0:50.0:300.0,
6x1080 Array{Int64,2}:
 1302  1288  1293  1302  1297  1300  1257  1234  …    12    13    13    12    13    15    14
  618   632   627   618   623   620   663   686      189   187   187   188   185   183   183
    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0        9     9     8     7     8     7     7
    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0       10    12     9     7    13     7     9
    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1238  1230  1236  1235  1230  1240  1234
    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0  …   462   469   467   471   471   468   473)
```

But, instead of 6x1080, I'd like 256 slots in the histogram to show total number of times each value has appeared. I tried:

```
julia> hist(img_gld_gs,256)
```

But that gives:

```
(2.0:1.0:252.0,
250x1080 Array{Int64,2}:
```

So instead of a 256x1080 Array, it's 250x1080. Is there any way to force it to have 256 bins (without resorting to writing my own hist function)? I want to be able to compare different images and I want the histogram for each image to have the same number of bins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`hist`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/base/#Base.hist) also accepts a vector (or range) as an optional argument that specifies the edge boundaries, so

```
hist(img_gld_gs, 0:256)
```

should work.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want a histogram for the entire image (rather than one per row), you might want

```
hist(vec(img_gld_gs), -1:255)
```

which first converts the image to a 1-dimensional vector. (You can also use `img_gld_gs[:]`, but that copies the data.)

Also note the range here: the hist function uses a left-open interval, so it will omit counting zeros unless you use something smaller than 0.

Comment: @tholy good point. Not sure yet, but may want a histogram per row for image comparisons - have to try both with an EMD to see which gives better comparison. Also, I would think I would want: hist(vec(img_gld_gs),0:255)    Why the -1 above?

Comment: @tholy: oh, I see why you're doing the -1.